# How to make a method for downloading a jasper report on Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jasper-reports

I made a jasper report, and all the fields, get the list of objects I need to pass on to it. Just don't know how to continue.

Comment: Please provide more details on what you are trying to accomplish, including any relevant code, to help solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Found it!

```
`response.setContentType("text/html");
JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list);
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reports/JasperReportName.jrxml");
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
//params.put("",""); if you have any params
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, dataSource);
inputStream.close();

response.setContentType("application/x-download");
response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=NameofPdf.pdf");
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint,out);`
```